# Hibernate save transient instance

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-entitymanager

So I have two entities with a bi-directional @ManyToMany relation - Student and Course. 
My Student class being:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@Column(name = "role", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String studentName;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "student_course",
           joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "student_id", 
referencedColumnName = "id")},
           inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "course_id",
                                             referencedColumnName = 
"id")})
private Set<Course> course = new HashSet<>();

public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
}

public void setStudentName(final String studentName) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
}

public Set<Course> getCourses() {
    return courses;
}

public void setCourses(final Set<Course> courses) {
    this.courses = courses;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    ...
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
   ...
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    ...
}
```

My Course class being:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@Column(name = "course", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String course;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "courses")
private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();

public String getCourse() {
    return course;
}

public void setCourse(final String course) {
    this.course = course;
}

public Set<Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
}

public void setStudents(final Set<Student> students) {
    this.students = students;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    ...
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    ...
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    ...
}
```

Using the hibernate entitymanager I want to persist both the entities. So in my DbInitializer(), I have something like this that fills data for the Course entity.

```
private Set<Course> initCourses() {
    final Set<Course> courses = 
    CourseProvider.getTestCourses();

    for (final Course course : courses) {
        entityManager.persist(course);
    }
    return courses;
}
```

This works fine. But when I try to fill data for the Student entity, it asks me save the transient instance before flushing.

```
private List<Student> initStudents() {  
    final Set<Student> students = StudentProvider.getTestStudents();
    for (final Student student : students) {
        entityManager.persist(student);
    }
    return students;
}
```

StudentProvider class:

```
public class StudentProvider {

public static List<Student> getTestStudentsList() {

    final List<Student> students = 
    StudentFactory.createStudents();
    return students;
}
```

}

StudentFactory class:

```
public class StudentFactory {

public static final List<Student> createStudents() {

    final EnumSet<StudentEnum> students = 
    EnumSet.allOf(StudentEnum.class);
    final List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (final StudentEnum s : students) {

        final Student student = new Student();
        student.setStudentName(s.toString());
        student.setCourses(s.transform());
        studentList.add(student);
    }

    return studentList;
}
```

The StudentProvider calls the StudentFactory that sets values for Student.
The StudentEnum has a list of students with the corresponding courses.

I am aware that cascade = CascadeType.ALL could solve the problem. I tried using it but, it gives me a "Duplicate Entry error for the Course entity". And if I don't use the cascade it asks me to save the transient instance.

Could someone please suggest me a way without using cascasde??? 
I understand that I have to save the Course entity before persisting the Student entity.

I went through a couple of Stackoverflow questions but I couldn't solve the problem. Help needed!
Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: provide plz `StudentProvider.getTestStudents()` implementation

Comment: @star67 I have edited the question and added StudentProvider() and StudentFactory(). Still struggling, please help!

Comment: how your `Course`s are created? provide plz implementation of `s.transform()`